# How can I handle nested arrays in this regex based JSON to XML converter

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, json, parsing

I just hacked together a json to xml converter, which more or less parses the json, and manipulates it directly into xml in the regex callback function. I have completely invented this method, so I am not sure if there are any obvious/terrible drawbacks or limitations - to date, parsing has been pretty much a mystery to me.

I put a lot of comments in there, so hopefully it is easy enough to follow.

### The Code

```
var cb = function(m,oo,co,st,s,ignore,cl,cm,oa,ca){

  // remove slashes from captured strings
  s = stripslashes(s)

  // this will be built, and returned at the end
  var xml = ""

  // function to add padding to the output, at the start of the lines
  var pad = function(q){ q--; q *= 4
    var out = ''
    for(;q--;) out += ' '
    return out
  }

  // track the arrat status, last item type, current indent level, and tags stack
  this.array = this.array || null
  this.last = this.last || null
  this.level = this.level || 0
  this.tags = this.tags || []

  // Handle opening braces
  if(oo){

    if(this.array && this.last.match(/^(cm|oa)$/)){
      xml += "\n"+pad(this.level)+"<item>"
      this.tags.push("item")
    }

    // increase the indentation level
    this.level++

    // set the last item, which should be the last thing to do in the block
    this.last = 'oo'

  // Handle closing braces
  } else if(co){

    // if the last item was not a string, then add padding
    if(this.last != 'st')
      xml += pad(this.level)

    // close a tag
    xml += "</"+this.tags.pop()+">\n"

    // decrease the indentation level
    this.level--

    // set the last item, which should be the last thing to do in the block
    this.last = 'co'

  // Handle Strings
  } else if(st){

    // Debug by showing the tags as they are pushed and popped from the stack
    // console.log(this.tags)

    // Handle Strings where last item was an Object, or a comma
    if(this.last == "oo" || this.last == "cm"){

      // add the tag to the stack, and xml output
      this.tags.push(s)
      xml += "\n"+pad(this.level)+"<"+s+">"

    // Handle Strings where last item was an Colon
    } else if(this.last == "cl"){
      xml += s
    }

    // set the last item, which should be the last thing to do in the block
    this.last = 'st'

  // Handle the opan arrays
  } else if(oa){
    this.array = 1
    this.level++
    xml += "\n"+pad(this.level)+"<array>"
    this.level++
    this.last = 'oa'

  // Handle the close arrays
  } else if(ca){
    this.array = 0
    xml += pad(this.level)+"</"+this.tags.pop()+">\n"
    this.level--
    xml += pad(this.level)+"</array>\n"
    this.level--
    this.last = 'ca'

  // Handle the colons
  } else if(cl){
    this.last = 'cl'

  // Handle the commas
  } else if(cm){
    if(this.last == "co")
      xml += pad(this.level)+"</"+this.tags.pop()+">"
    else
      xml += "</"+this.tags.pop()+">"
    this.last = 'cm'
  }

  // return the built xml
  return xml

}


// DEPENDENCY
function stripslashes (str) {

  return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
    switch (n1) {
    case '\\':
      return '\\';
    case '0':
      return '\u0000';
    case '':
      return '';
    default:
      return n1;
    }
  });
}

// DATA FOR TESTING
var o = {
  "hash":"b6f6991d03df0e2e04dafffcd6bc418aac66049e2cd74b80f14ac86db1e3f0da",
  "ver":1,
  "vin_sz":1,
  "vout_sz":2,
  "lock_time":"Unavailable",
  "size":258,
  "relayed_by":"64.179.201.80",
  "block_height": 12200,
  "tx_index":"12563028",
  "inputs":[
    { "prev_out":{
        "hash":"a3e2bcc9a5f776112497a32b05f4b9e5b2405ed9",
        "value":"100000000",
        "tx_index":"12554260",
        "n":"2"
      },
      "scriptSig":"Unavailable"
    },
    { "prev_out":{
        "hash":"a3e2bcc9a5f776112497a32b05f4b9e5b2405ed9",
        "value":"100000000",
        "tx_index":"12554260",
        "n":"2"
      },
      "scriptSig":"Unavailable"
    },
    { "prev_out":{
        "hash":"a3e2bcc9a5f776112497a32b05f4b9e5b2405ed9",
        "value":"100000000",
        "tx_index":"12554260",
        "n":"2"
      },
      "scriptSig":"Unavailable"
    },
    { "prev_out":{
        "hash":"a3e2bcc9a5f776112497a32b05f4b9e5b2405ed9",
        "va'l\"u'e":"1000\"00000",
        "tx_index":"12554260",
        "n":"2"
      },
      "scriptSig":"Unavailable"
    }
  ],
  "out":[
    { "value":"98000000",
      "hash":"29d6a3540acfa0a950bef2bfdc75cd51c24390fd",
      "scriptPubKey":"Unavailable"
    },
    { "value":"2000000",
      "hash":"17b5038a413f5c5ee288caa64cfab35a0c01914e",
      "scriptPubKey":"Unavailable"
    }
  ]
}

var s = JSON.stringify(o)

console.log("Original: "+s+"\n")

// var r = /({)|(})|([""''])(.+?)\3|(:)|(,)|(\[)|(\])/g

// THE REGEX
// capturing groups map to -> m,oo,co,st,s,ignore,cl,cm,oa,ca in the callback
// meaning match, open-object, close-object, string-type, string, ignore, colon, comma, open-array, close-array
// string escaping made possible by... `(['"])((\\\3|[^\3])+?)\3`
var r = /({)|(})|(['"])((\\\3|[^\3])+?)\3|(:)|(,)|(\[)|(\])/g

var xml = s.replace(r,cb)

console.log(xml)
```

### Questions

1. How can I add support for nested arrays?
2. What is this technique for parsing called?
3. Is the string escaping method solid?
4. Is this a viable method for parsing?
5. Is there a more general solution using this method?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to write my own parsers

Comment: I think you really should use `JSON.parse`. If you want to check JSON parsers, have a look at [this overview](http://json.org/)

Comment: For parsing nested structures, you will need to implement a stack.

Comment: @BillyMoon Have you found the solution? Can you please answer your own post?

Comment: @AmitGupta I did not pursue this any further. I ended up making a PEG parser using peg.js. I don’t think this method can work really. The regex tries to convert whole string into tokens, but this is not possible without context of previous tokens - for example nested arrays can not be detecteds without knowing where you are in the structure somehow. Also, I don’t think depth is enough, probably need to track type of node visited to create at least a stack of open/close quotes/brackets etc... or maybe just a tree (an AST maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for your own solution, I believe you mean understanding how a parser works in this case.

> How can I add support for nested arrays?

An array can be the collection of value, object,and an array. So write a method which handles value, array, and object separately. Now when you meet to an array or object inside the array call the same function.

I'm not sure about other questions. But here is the solution I used in [fast xml parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser)

```
var j2x = function(jObj,level){
    var xmlStr = "", attrStr = "" , val = "";
    var keys = Object.keys(jObj);
    var len = keys.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var key = keys[i];
        if(typeof jObj[key] !== "object"){//premitive type
            var attr = this.isAttribute(key);
            if(attr){
                attrStr += " " +attr+"=\""+ this.encodeHTMLchar(jObj[key], true) +"\"";
            }else if(this.isCDATA(key)){
                if(jObj[this.options.textNodeName]){
                    val += this.replaceCDATAstr(jObj[this.options.textNodeName], jObj[key]);
                }else{
                    val += this.replaceCDATAstr("", jObj[key]);
                }
            }else{//tag value
                if(key === this.options.textNodeName){
                    if(jObj[this.options.cdataTagName]){
                        //value will added while processing cdata
                    }else{
                        val += this.encodeHTMLchar(jObj[key]);    
                    }
                }else{
                    val += this.buildTextNode(jObj[key],key,"",level);
                }
            }
        }else if(Array.isArray(jObj[key])){//repeated nodes
            if(this.isCDATA(key)){
                if(jObj[this.options.textNodeName]){
                    val += this.replaceCDATAarr(jObj[this.options.textNodeName], jObj[key]);
                }else{
                    val += this.replaceCDATAarr("", jObj[key]);
                }
            }else{//nested nodes
                var arrLen = jObj[key].length;
                for(var j=0;j<arrLen;j++){
                    var item = jObj[key][j];
                    if(typeof item === "object"){
                        var result = this.j2x(item,level+1);
                        val  += this.buildObjNode(result.val,key,result.attrStr,level);
                    }else{
                        val += this.buildTextNode(item,key,"",level);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{

            if(this.options.attrNodeName && key === this.options.attrNodeName){
                var Ks = Object.keys(jObj[key]);
                var L = Ks.length;
                for(var j=0;j<L;j++){
                    attrStr += " "+Ks[j]+"=\"" + this.encodeHTMLchar(jObj[key][Ks[j]]) + "\"";
                }
            }else{
                var result = this.j2x(jObj[key],level+1);
                val  += this.buildObjNode(result.val,key,result.attrStr,level);
            }
        }
    }
    return {attrStr : attrStr , val : val};
}
```